# Wrong calculation of collector current

Tags: transistors, common-emitter

There is a transistor circuit which I am DC analysing.

I did KVL to find base current.

-5 + Ib.10k + Vbe(0.7V) = 0

Ib = 0.43mA

Hfe of NPN transistor is 100.

Ic = hfe.IB, Ic = 0.43mA*100

Ic = 43mA

But simulation says that there is 2.389 mA current flows to collector.

Whats wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Please show your circuit. We cannot answer your question without seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation assumed that the transistor was in forward-active mode, but you did not actually verify that assumption.

If the collector current were indeed 43 mA, then the voltage drop across the network on the right would mean that the collector voltage would be -203 V; this shows you that the forward active assumption is incorrect.

You should instead be treating the transistor as if it were in saturation mode -- the base current is still correct since it depends on the base resistor and Vbe (of about 0.6-0.7 V), However, the collector current is not hFE * base current; almost all of the voltage drop is across the resistor network on the right.

Comment: Oh, that's the point that i was missing. Thank you. Well how can i calculate collector current here ?  Should i check it from datasheet? Btw the transistor is BC817.

Comment: @Kırambor you would look up the saturation voltage in the datasheet, and assume that Vce (collector voltage - emitter voltage) is equal to that value. Then you can solve for the current in the resistors using ohms law and/or Thévenin equivalent.

Comment: In saturation mode the base current has two portions: (1) Current through the B-E junction and (b) current hrough the B-C junction which is also forward biased in saturation mode. Therefore, the relation Ic=(hfe * Ib) does not apply anymore.

Comment: In Saturation mode hFE can be often rated by 10:1=Ic:Ib which affects Vce(sat). Thus forward active of Vcb shunts hFE to about 10% to 20% of max linear hFE